# MIPS Bad address in data/stack read

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I've spent hours looking at this, printing out addresses and can't figure it out. This is a simple assembly program run through QTSpim. Program meant to take in values for an array of size 20, find two smallest integers in an array, adds and returns them to main where they are then stored into memory in locations right after the array.

The program takes in the 20 values for the array, but then tries to calculate and spits out Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10040000. All my other data is in 0x100100XX memory locations, no idea why 40000 is coming up.

```
.data
Fresh: .space 80
freshSmallestSum: space 4

.text
sumMin:
    lw      $t2, 0($a0) # $t2 = smallest array[i]
    addi    $t4, $t0, 1 # $t4 = i + 1
    sll     $t4, $t4, 2 # $t4 = i * (2^2)
    add     $t4, $t4, $a0   # $t4 = absolute address array[i+1]
    lw      $t3, 0($t4) # $t3 = array[i+1]
    li      $t4, 2      # i = 2
    ble     $t2, $t3, loopSmall # if $t2 <= t3 jump
    move    $t9, $t2
    move    $t2, $t3
    move    $t3, $t9
loopSmall:
    bge     $t4, $t1, ret1
    sll     $t5, $t4, 2 # $t5 = i * (2^2)
    add     $t5, $t5, $a0   # absolute address array[i]
    lw      $t5, 0($t5) # $t5 = array[i]
    ble     $t3, $t5, next2 # if $t3 <= array[i], jump
    move    $t3, $t5    # else $t3 = array[i]
    ble     $t2, $t3, next2 # if $t2 <= $t3, jump
    move    $t9, $t2    # else swap two smallest
    move    $t2, $t3
    move    $t3, $t9
next2:
    addi    $t4, $t4, 1 # i++
    j   loopSmall
ret1:
    add     $v0, $t2, $t3   # $v0 = smallest + secondSmallest
    jr      $ra

.text
.globl main
main: 
    li      $t3, 0
    li      $t0, 0      # i = 0
    li      $t1, 20     # $t1 = 20
    la      $s2, Fresh

inLoop: 
    bge $t3, $t1, next  # If $t3 > array length, jump
    sll     $t2, $t3, 2
    add     $t4, $t2, $s2   # Absolute address of fresh
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw      $v0, 0($t4)
    addi    $t3, $t3, 1 # Increment counter
    j       inLoop      
move        $a0, $s2    # $a0 = address Fresh
    jal     sumMax      # Get max sum of Fresh
    la      $t1, freshLargestSum
    sw      $v0, 0($t1) # Store sum in freshLargestSum

    move    $a0, $s2
    jal     sumMin      # Get min sum of Fresh
    la      $t1, freshSmallestSum
    sw      $v0, 0($t1) # Store sum in freshSmallestSum

exit:       li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Use your simulator to single step the code and see which instruction is faulting. Then check register values and spot which is bad, then work backwards to see how it got the bad value. PS: I can't even find the label `next`, copy-paste error or do you really not have it? Also, `sumMin` seems to expect the array size in `$t1` but that contains address of `freshLargestSum` at that point.

Comment: Sorry - definitely was copy paste error - the program is much longer than this code segment. Trying to cut only the relevant pieces. And the $t1 was the error! Thanks so much - that little register change was not close in the code to the sumMin piece so I didn't catch it. Hours of future staring fixed by your comment, thank you!

Comment: You should always test the code you're actually posting for debug help, especially if you're a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the code here looks great, but this is not the complete file?

It would seem your sumMin function wants the array-size as t1 but it is giving a freshLargestSum address?

Have you tried stepping through the code line by line?
Especially with MIPS, most errors are usually overwriting registers that we need later on in the code; especially when we are jumping back.

A good debugging technique is also to test that the functions all work as expected independently; if so you know that the error resides in the main code; and is likely to do with:

- Overwritten registers
- jal to the wrong place
- Overwriting the return register
- Incorrect logic

Hopefully this helps you to solve your problem!